# Redis Connection with Cache is failing

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, visual-studio-2017

Goal:
Enable to use  Redis Cache in a asp.net core sample project from this webpage.
(https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/06/using-redis-cache-net-core/)

Problem:
When I follow the instruction and use the source code I get a error message saying

```
"StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: 'It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING"
```

Q1.
What part of the website or the source code am I missing?

Q2.
Do you need an account at Redis in order use an unique IP number that should be applied at "option.Configuration = "127.0.0.1";"?

Info:
Using VS 2017 asp.net core mvc 2.2

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: So asking the obvious, if you're trying to connect to Redis locally.. you have installed Redis locally right?

Comment: "you have installed Redis locally right" I didn't know that you need to have install Redis locally according to tutorial.

Comment: if I understand, you need to install Redis in locally in order to make the sourcode above to be working?